# Reactivity issue, Svelte, Radio button

Tags: svelte

My case is that I have multiple objects in an array. The user should (via radio button) select which item should be used.

However, the user shall also be able to change the name of object (obj.name).

The value shall be stored elsewhere, but it must be the obj.name of the selected object.

Here is a sample code (works out of the box in Svelte REPL):

```
<script>
    let selectedName = "";
    let arr = [];
    let obj1 = {};
    obj1.id = 1;
    obj1.name = "One";
    let obj2 = {};
    obj2.id = 2;
    obj2.name = "Two";
    let obj3 = {};
    obj3.id = 3;
    obj3.name = "Three";

    arr.push(obj1);
    arr.push(obj2);
    arr.push(obj3);
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={selectedName}/>
<hr>
{#each arr as row}
    <input type="radio" bind:group={selectedName} value={row.name}/> {row.id}
    <input type="text" bind:value={row.name}/>
    <br/>
{/each}
```

In this example, all renders nicely, you can select 1, 2 or 3, and the textbox above gets updated with the name of the object ("One", "Two" or "Three").

If you select 2 and then change the name of 1 from "One" to "Uno", and then select 1 - the value is changed to "Uno" in the textbox above. BUT! If you now change the text from "Uno" to "Ein" - the textbox doesn't update.

The natural thing would be to have the radio button bind the value, like this:

```
    <input type="radio" bind:group={selectedName} bind:value={row.name}/> {row.id}
```

... but then everything just gets messed up completely! :-)

Is there anyone that can shine a light over this, I'd be very happy!

And to clarify; the solution of storing the id instead of name is not the solution to my problem. Above example is just a simplified version to illustrate the issue.

Comment: The reason why your textbox is not updating is because you're not modifying `selectedName` (i.e. you're not triggering an event on the radio inputs), you're only modifying the value that will be affected to `selectedName` next time you select that option. If you do as you mentioned in your question, then select 2 again, then go back to 1, the textbox *will* update to `Ein` because it is now the value of that radio option.

Comment: Modifying the *value* of a radio input will not trigger an event to affect that value to `selectedName`. If that's your goal, you will have to do that manually (programmatically) when the value is updated (i.e. in the onChange event handler of the row textbox).

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot - that explains why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I got an approach that works by displaying a reactive variable, called `name`, in the text input. I defined the reactive variable to be `arr[selectedIndex].name`, and `selectedIndex` is the value associated with selecting a radio button.

Code that works out of the box in the Svelte REPL:

```
<script>
    let arr = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "One"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Two"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Three"
        }
    ];
    let selectedIndex;
    let name = "";
    $: {
        if (selectedIndex !== undefined) {
            name = arr[selectedIndex].name;
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="text" value={name} />
<hr />
{#each arr as row, index}
    <input type="radio" bind:group={selectedIndex} value={index} />
    {row.id}
    <input type="text" bind:value={row.name}/>
    <br/>
{/each}
```

Comment: This is a great solution! A more concise way of writing the logic would be to replace `let name` and the `$: {}` block with this line `$: selectedName = arr[selectedIndex]?.name ?? ''`

Comment: Hi, thanks, but using index is the same workaround as using the ID. As I wrote in the question, I don't want to do a workaround here (I already have a workaround that solved it for me, by using the ID instead), but I would rather like to make use of reactivity in Svelte and above all, understand why the code in the question doesn't work.

Comment: @Krillegeddon but isn't this code achieving what you were after? In the end `selectedName` is reactively updated and set to the text value of the corresponding selected radio button - that's what you tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

When adding a log of the radio button on text input change, it can be seen that the value of the radio button changes accordingly even without adding the `bind:value` >> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/438186b00b9a4322806d3e3a55770789?version=3.44.1)

```html
<script>    
    let arr = [
        { id: 1, name: "One" },
        { id: 2, name: "Two" },
        { id: 3, name: "Three" }
    ];
        let selectedName = "";
    
    function checkRadioValue(event) {
        console.log(document.getElementById(event.target.dataset.id))
    }
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={selectedName}/>
<hr>
{#each arr as row}
    <input type="radio" bind:group={selectedName} value={row.name} id={row.id}/> {row.id}
    <input type="text" bind:value={row.name} on:input={checkRadioValue} data-id={row.id}/>
    <br/>
{/each}
```

What doesn't happen is the update of the `bind:group` value. This only seems to be triggered on a change event of the radio buttons, looks like this is *"the main problem"*.

Here's another example using `bind:group` with radio buttons and checkboxes >> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d9023e3b9be346388d582bb3adb4b98d?version=3.44.1)
Click on the button down below to change both array contents -> the displayed values get instantly updated (no `bind:value` needed for that), but the values saved in `selectedScoop/selectedFlavours` displayed above do not. Only after changing a radio button or check mark directly the values react to modifications.

So a possible way to achieve the desired functionality (alternatively to the reactive approach via the id/index) would be to handle the focus and input event on the input fields >> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f38bb9f252fc472e897023ba97d043f8?version=3.44.1)

```html
<script>
    let arr = [
        { id: 1, name: "One" },
        { id: 2, name: "Two" },
        { id: 3, name: "Three"}
    ];
    let selectedName    

    function handleTextInputEvents(event) {
        selectedName = event.target.value
    }
</script>

{selectedName}

<hr />
{#each arr as row, index (row.id)}
    <input type="radio" name="names" bind:group={selectedName} value={row.name}/>
    {row.id}
    <input type="text" bind:value={row.name} on:focus={handleTextInputEvents} on:input={handleTextInputEvents}/>
    <br/>
{/each}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I should have been more clear in my post; I have a working solution based on using the id instead, but I am curious to why this doesn't work with standard Svelte reactivity.

Perhaps it simply doesn't?

Comment: @Krillegeddon by `this` you mean why only using `bind:group` doesn't do what you want it to? Because it seems only to be updated with a change event of the group. If you'd like to know why that is, you might reduce this (/a new) question to exactly that point...

Comment: @Krillegeddon I just added another example to the answer which maybe better illustrates the behavour (feel free to use it for asking why..)

Answer (score 0):

In relation to my comment to your question, here is a workaround using a tailored event handler on the row input box that will update the checked option (in addition to updating unchecked options):

```
<input type="text" value={row.name} on:input={(e) => {
  const { target } = e
  row.name = target.value
  const radio = target.previousElementSibling
  if (radio.checked) {
    selectedName = target.value
  }
}} />
```

[Demo REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8f52a7d9a6864a698d671bcabd0bb8fe?version=3)